# Automatic list organisation

Tags: trello, list

Is it possible, if I have lists like "Past", "Today", "Tomorrow", "Future" and I set due dates, that cards will automatically change lists by date? So if the task hasn't been done today, that it will automatically move to "Past" list the next day?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Trello?